# How to add entry to /etc/hosts with a built-in command line

Tags: command-line, hosts

It turns out that editing `/etc/hosts`  is enough to add an entry of DNS.

Is there a built-in cmd , where we can:

1. add host

   **cmd**: `$ sudo mycmd 10.103.23.34  myme.com`

   **Result** : `10.103.23.34  myme.com`
2. Add hostname

   **cmd**    : `$ sudo mycmd 10.103.23.34 omac.org`

   **Result** : `10.103.23.34  myme.com omac.org`
3. Modify IP

   **cmd**    : `$ sudo mycmd 10.103.23.18 omac.org`

   **Result** : `10.103.23.18  myme.com omac.org`

Comment: It's not clear to me why changing the IP for `omac.org` should change the IP for `myme.org`.

Comment: let's say the wanted cmd will search on lines that contain `omac.org` , & if it found those lines , it will replace old IP by new IP ... If you recommend another scenario , it will be great

Comment: There's no such tool, but you could script it yourself. Also, what will happen if `10.103.23.18` is already mapped to some hostname?

Comment: `sudo echo 127.1.2.3 hostname.example.com >> /etc/hosts` should be enough for adding entries.  Removing them would probably be a simple `sed` command, also run through sudo.  Sanity-checking for duplicate host names with `grep` is also straightforward enough.

Comment: You can add new entry to /etc/hosts with `sed -i` and `$ a` option, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50003244/658497

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeking for CLI for `/etc/hosts` , we find : https://github.com/macmade/host-manager

**Amazing** :

```
host-manager -add www.example.org 127.0.0.1
host-manager -remove www.example.org
```

Comment: Great find! Unfortunately it seems not to work for me...

Answer (score 2):

I tried to get the host-manager tool listed above to work but it looks like maybe it's for Windows or macOS? It was trying to cross compile and didn't look right for Ubuntu. I found this tool 'Hostess' though which works great and seems to do exactly what the OP was looking for:

https://github.com/cbednarski/hostess

```
hostess add local.example.com 127.0.0.1
hostess add staging.example.com 10.0.2.16
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to other suggestions - there's one more option which exists in standard Ubuntu package repositories - `hostsed` ([github page + docs here](https://github.com/socrateslee/hostsed)). As a result install is as easy as `apt install hostsed`.